# SSAS Project error connecting to workspace

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssas

I'm just learning, so please bear with me. I'm trying to create an Analysis Services project in Visual Studio 2013, but when I try to connect to the workspace server, I'm getting the following error:

Cannot connect to server '[servername]'. Reason: The workspace database '[servername]' is not running in tabular mode.

Can someone please tell me what this error means and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to go to Workspace Server property of BIM file and enter the SSAS instance that is setup for Tabular Mode. You're probably trying to use SSAS Multidimensional server for Tabular project.

Answer (score 0):

1. open sql-server management studio and Create a database in sql server analysis services
2. open visual studio and use import from sever option and give name same as the one given above(point 1)[image]
3. give desired location to share the visual studio solution